# show selection pointers and highlight text in textview with longclick

Tags: android

I have a TextView that I want to implement LongClickListner on and select part of the text in it... However selection pointers don't appear and the text is not highlighted.
I know the text is selected because when I use view.getselectionstart() and view.getselectionend() they return the right values...below the code I use:

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
   Selection.setSelection((Spannable) textView.getText(),5, 10);
   v.setSelected(true);
   return true;
}
 });
```

This doesn't show any thing.....But when I try to log selection start and end:

```
Log.d("SELECTED TEXT LISTNER",Selection.getSelectionStart(textView.getText())
+ " " +Selection.getSelectionEnd(textView.getText()));
```

the right values (5, 10) are returned...any help how I can show selection pointers and highlight on longclick??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Programatically:

```
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

You won't need to implement your own `onLongClickListener` as the default behaviour is as you described.